# ASP.NET WEB API on localhost

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ASP.NET WEB Api on IIS on localhost and I have an other MVC App which on IIS Express.
I would like to call web api from jquery ajax, but it is not successfull.

web api: `localhost/WebApi/api/values`

MVC app: `localhost:44305/`

I am using IE 11. I checked with fiddler that request is not process but I get an error message that:

```
"0:Error:Access Denied".
```

Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Cross-Origin Requests issue. You should EnableCors() in your web.api application

Open the file App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. Add the following code to the WebApiConfig.Register method.

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace WebService
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
        // New code
        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
}
```

For more detail look at [this page](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: yeah that probably the problem.  OP could've included a lot more information to help out though

Comment: You can find detailed information on [http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)